# Nestled if else and loop help python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Two questions:

1. How can I nestle `if` + `else` statements between other `if` + `else` statements?
2. How can I loop back to the top of my code when the `else` statement is activated?

Here's the code:

```
print("Welcome To Your Workstation.")
usrname = input("Username: ")
pssword = input("Password: ")
if usrname=="Harry" and pssword=="password123":
    print("-=-=-=Welcome=-=-=-")
    print("Enter A Program Name")
    print("You can use:add_up")
    program = input(":")
    if program=="add_up":
            print("Ok, Lets Get Adding!")
            num1 = input(int(float("Enter Your First Number: ")
            num2 = input(int(float("Enter Your Second Number: ")
            num3 = input(int(float("Enter Your Third Number: ")
            answer = num1 + num2 + num3
            print(num1"+"num2"+"num3"="answer)
    else:
        print("Unknown Command, Reboot And Try Again.")

else:
    print("Incorrect Password, Reboot And Try Again"
```

I am a python noob in need of help :)

Comment: use a `while` loop, you already have your if/else nested so not sure what your question is there

Comment: Thanks, very suprised on response time, Great!

Comment: You should also consider when you want the loop to end, you probably  don't want to loop forever so you should give the user an option to end the loop ie when they enter `q`, if they enter q then `break` the loop

Comment: I know this is not part of the question, but what are you trying to achieve by calling input(int(float("text"))? this should cause a syntax error anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use a while loop.

```
print("Welcome To Your Workstation.")
usrname = input("Username: ")
pssword = input("Password: ")
while True:
    if usrname=="Harry" and pssword=="password123":
        print("-=-=-=Welcome=-=-=-")
        print("Enter A Program Name")
        print("You can use:add_up")
        program = input(":")
        if program=="add_up":
            print("Ok, Lets Get Adding!")
            num1 = input(int(float("Enter Your First Number: ")
            num2 = input(int(float("Enter Your Second Number: ")
            num3 = input(int(float("Enter Your Third Number: ")
            answer = num1 + num2 + num3
            print(num1"+"num2"+"num3"="answer)
        break
   else:
        print("Unknown Command, Reboot And Try Again.")

else:
    print("Incorrect Password, Reboot And Try Again"
```

Comment: `while True` and `break`, a flag is unnecessary for a single loop

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit classier. Updated.

Comment: You also need move the username and password in the loop or the code will loop infinitely  if the username and pass are not correct

Comment: I realise that you just copy & pasted that crazy `input(int(float(...)))` stuff from the OP, but would you mind fixing it? That way, future readers will get more benefit from your answer.

Comment: I don't even know what he's trying to do there and whether he wants to use float or int. I'm not using python3 but I don't think those lines would compile, anyway. I'm leaving the answer as-is, as this is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: the `else` of a `while True:`-loop is never reached.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a `while` loop. It works like this:

```
while expr:
    stuff to do
```

`expr` can be any valid expression, just like you would use in an `if` statement.

`stuff to do` can be any code, including more loops, `if` statements and so on.

There are a couple of ways to exit a while loop:

1. Make `expr` false. For example, if your expression is `len(myword) < 10`, add some more characters to `myword`. The value of `expr` is only evaluated between each run of your `stuff to do` block.
2. Raise an exception. This is usually used when problems arise, and will make your code jump all the way up the stack to a matching `except` statement, catching the exception.
3. Use the `break` keyword, which immediately stops the nearest enclosing loop.

In your case, alternatives 1 or 3 are the best candidates. They would look something like this:

```
keeprunning = True
while keeprunning:
    if something:
        keeprunning = False
    print('this will still be printed after keeprunning was changed')
```

and

```
while True:
    if something:
        break
    print('this won\'t be printed if the break is executed')
```